# python pyside6 change button icon outside main window class

Tags: python, function, class, icons, pyside

I have an application developed by pyside6; it switches themes when the system changes themes. code show as below:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
     ...#main window code here

def set_theme():#function to change theme.(I use a timer to call this function.)
    if darkdetect.isDark():
        App.setStyleSheet(dark_style_sheet)
        #Need to change icon in this line.
    else:
        App.setStyleSheet(light_style_sheet)   
        #Need to change icon in this line. 
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUItimer = QTimer()
    GUItimer.timeout.connect(get_theme)
    GUItimer.start(300)
    ...
```

Right now it works fine, but I need `setIcon` to put the icon on the button, and it should sets the icon when the theme changes (light themes have black icons, dark themes have white icons), but `set_theme()` funtion is outside the Class `Ui_MainWindow`, so I cannot call the button of the `MainWindow` in the `set_theme()` function. Is there any way to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Since Qt5.15 QPushButton supports the `icon` property; you can use the [object name selector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) to set it. Alternatively, consider using a custom QIcon theme along with [`QIcon.fromTheme()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme) (or with the "Theme" field of the `icon` property in Designer), so that you can switch icon themes easily.

Comment: Thank you! I solve the problem by made a qss file for them.